# How to request Feign with Authentication JWT Bearer Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-feign

> I use two service in java spring service core and service shop, i want to insert data from service core with method in service core, but in service core i need to bearer token, how to i send auth bearer token from service shop to service core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing `RequestInterceptor` to set Authentication to request header.

```
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null && RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
            HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
            String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(authorization)) {
                template.header("Authorization", new String[]{authorization});
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Naturally you need a way to obtain your service token from a well known OAuth endpoint using a `client-credentials` grant type

If you want to do it on a per integration basis, perhaps because you are integrating with different services using different approaches, you can do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.GET], value = ["/id/{id}"], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE], consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
operator fun get(
    @RequestHeader("Authorization") bearerToken: String = "Bearer mybiglongencodedtoken....",
    @PathVariable("id") code: String,
```